# How to call an object from Main class to another C#

Tags: c#, class, object

I am trying to call an object from one class to another in C#. How do I do this?

Here is a snippet of my code:

```cs
public bool IsPositionFree(int x, int y)
{
    if (x < 0 || y < 0 || x >= Cols || y >= Rows)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return Maze[y, x] == " " || Maze[y, x] == "E" || *** Here is where I want to check if y,x is equal to my treasure object (Treasure t1) that I have drawn to my screen *** ;
}
```

In my main programme I have created an object and this is what I want to call to my other class

```cs
public static Treasure t1;

Treasure t1 = new Treasure(1, 3);
```

My Treasure class is -

```cs
class Treasure
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }
    public string Gold;
    private ConsoleColor TreasureColour;
    private int TreasureValue = 100;

    public Treasure(int initialx , int initialy)
    {
        x = initialx;
        y = initialy;
        Gold = "T";
        TreasureColour = ConsoleColor.Yellow;       
    }

    public void DrawTreasure()
    {       
        ConsoleColor Color = TreasureColour;
        Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
        Console.Write(Gold);

    }
}
```

Comment: Please post an [mcve]. What public methods/fields does `Treasure` expose? Have you even defined a `Treasure` class?

Comment: @jwdonahue I have now added my treasure class

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, but do you mean to checvk if the coordinates match your treasure:  `if (x == t1.x && y == t1.y) // coordinates match treasure`

Comment: Is `IsPositionFree` in the same class as your declaration and initialization of `t1`: `public static Treasure t1;  Treasure t1 = new Treasure(1, 3);`?  If yes, then @RufusL has the solution for you.  Otherwise, you'll have to preface `t1` with the name of the class in which it resides, i.e., use `SomeClassName.t1`.  Do you see the benefit of showing enough code so that others can tell what you are asking?

Comment: @RufusL Hi, Yeah so basically I want to check if the x and y co-ordinates match the objects position that I have set in my main application.

Comment: what problem are you encountering? you have the `x` and `y` values declared as public properties already. Why can't you just compare them?

Comment: @RufusL Thank you Rufus! I solved my problem. I called Program.t1 and that worked for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your `Treasure t1` is defined in `Program`...
Your return will look like:

```cs
            
            return Maze[y, x] == " " || Maze[y, x] == "E" || (x == Program.t1.x && y == Program.t1.y);
```

Comment: This works, but everywhere else you might test for treasure, you have to write that expression perfectly, and it's not as immediately clear what the intent is, especially if it is expressed incorrectly. Logic like this should be wrapped in a method somewhere.

Comment: Sure, but i think he was just after an easy fix/solution.  Can't teach thorough encapsulation and OO/reusable programming from his question...

Comment: You can and should always teach proper design/code hygiene, especially when dealing with newbs.

Answer (score 1):

If they are in the same Namespace, you can just directly Type the ClassName within a line.
If dont you have to import in the class target like:

"using MyProject.Classes"

You have ClassA :

```
namespace ExampleNamespace
{
  public class ClassA 
  {
      public string  fieldA  {get;set;} 

      public void DoSomething(int variable)
      {
         //doing something
      }
  
   }
}
```

And you have ClassB that uses ClassA:

```
using ExampleNamespace;

public class ClassB
{
    public string randomField  {get;set;} 

    public void DoSomethingButBetter(int variable)
    {
         ClassA classA = new ClassA();
         classA.DoSomething(1);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your Treasure class:

```
public bool isLocationMatch(int x, int y) => x == this.x && y == this.y;
```

Then you have some work to do. You have to think about how `IsPositionFree` can be made aware of `t1`. But you haven't posted an [mcve] yet, so it's hard for me to say exactly how you would use the new method. You can probably work it out on your own.

The call would look something like `t1.isLocationMatch(x, y)`.

---

From a design perspective, you might want to think about maintaining a model of the X/Y plane. A 2d array of `object` or base class perhaps?

Comment: Not sure that method really helps, since `x` andf `y` are already public properties..?

Comment: @RufusL, See [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). You wind up repeating yourself, everywhere you need to test for Treasure, and typing out the full logic expression is far more error prone than `t1.isLocationMatch(x,y)`. It's also easier on your code reviewers eyes.

Comment: How does this even answer his question?  You give him a lesson and make it more confusing?  And tell him he has a lot more work to do?

Comment: It is a correct answer to the OP's question. I am not responsible for your confusion in this regard, and I don't understand why you even care at this point. The OP tagged your response as the answer, so they don't seem to be confused.

Comment: Also keep in mind that the OP edited their post while I was responding and they still haven't posted an [mcve], so I did what I could with the available data and 30 years of professional experience.

Comment: Sure, DRY is an optimization, but this doesn't answer the question about how to access the values (which can be done without the additional method).

Comment: @RufusL, the very same values are accessed with this method, the fact that there are other ways to achieve the end result, in no way indicates that I have posted a non-answer.

Comment: True, I guess I was reading the question like, *"How can I access some public properties of a static field in a different class?"* and this answer said, *"First add a public method to the type, and then access the properties through that method."*

Comment: @RufusL, Newbs almost always present us with [XY problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). They attempt to express their solutions using their current knowledge set, until they get stuck. Sometimes they ask questions that elicit one or more correct answers, sometimes, they get answers that actually advance their skill-set. You gave a good answer that provided a single increment of knowledge, I tried to suggest something with a little more content.